# Convergence in measure imply integrals converge?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is a measure space such that $\mu(X)<\infty$, and let $(f_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of measurable functions converging in measure to a measurable function $f$.

Does this imply that $$\int_{X} f d\mu =  \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{X} f_{n}  d\mu ?$$

All I know is that if $f_{n} \to f$ in measure, then there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_{j}})_{j \geq 1}$ such that $f_{n_{j}} \to f$ $\mu$- almost everywhere which implies the above, but I do not know if this is true for the sequence in general.

Comment: @saz I suppose the latter. I will edit the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, even if the sequence converges pointwise, this is, in general, not satisfied.

Just consider $X=(0,1)$, $\mu$ Lebesgue measure and the sequence

$$f_n(x) := n \cdot 1_{(0,1/n)}(x), \qquad x \in (0,1).$$

**Remark:** Vitali's convergence theorem implies $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n \, d\mu = \int f \, d\mu$$ for any sequence $f_n$ (converging to measure in $f$) which is uniformly integrable; see e.g.

*René Schilling: Measures, integrals and martingales*, Theorem 16.6

for a proof of (this version of) Vitali's convergence theorem. The assumption on the uniform integrability is in particular satisfied if $|f_n| \leq g$ for some integrable function $g$ (not depending on $n$).

Comment: I'm confused by your counterexample, because your functions $f_n$ don't seem to converge in measure to a measurable function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Vectornaut $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$. Note that for any $x \in (0,1)$, we have $f_n(x)=0$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Oh, dear—I've mixed up convergence in measure and $L^1$ convergence. So sorry!

Comment: @saz great answer; indeed I was looking for this to be satisfied in order to apply Vitali's convergence theorem. The only versions of vitali's theorem I have seen require that $f_{n} \to f$ a.e. Do you have a link or some other reference showing an example of vitali's convergence theorem where only convergence in measure is needed? I have not been able to find this, but this would solve the dilemma with the proof I am doing.

Comment: @möbius I have added a reference to my answer.